# Google Places AutoComplete Service (Street-City-State-Postcode) specific to country

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-places-api, google-places

I am working on Google Places AutoComplete Service where I need to filter the places specific to country !!

Reference Site :-- 
https://www.grubhub.com (specific country, city-state-zip)

I have found one example :--
http://plnkr.co/QjPEczt6AosghVP8EHNV

I need the autocomplete to give suggestion specific to country with Street Address-city-state-pincode format.

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Devang

Comment: What have you tried this far? Could you add into your question some code which could then be improved by answers?

Comment: Thanks Sami...  I have found one example :--
http://plnkr.co/QjPEczt6AosghVP8EHNV

Comment: The idea of SO is more or less to produce answers to specific programming questions ie. you might get better/more answers, if you try first programming something on your own, then produce results and point out where you have trouble.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as (using France as an example)...

```
GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlace("apiKey");
List<Predictions> predictions = client.getPlacePredictions(input, -1, -1, -1, -1, null, null, "fr");
for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
    String descriptions = prediction.getDescription();
    Place place = prediction.getPlace();
    // blah blah blah
}
```

...in [this](https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java) library.